# How could I define an R data.table/data.frame column from a function parameter?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, data.table, r-package

I have created a function in an R package which takes several arguments. One of these arguments is the name of a column for an R data.table.

Let's say I wanted to create a column with all values `42`. For R data.table `dt`, I would do:

```
dt[, column_name:=42]
```

For R data.frame, I would do:

```
df$column_name = 42
```

I would like the function to take as an argument something that would define `column_name`. For instance, the function `func` called by

```
func(dt, col='hey')
```

would pass `hey` as the new name of the data.table column.

Here's a concrete example

```
renamer = function(colname, dt){
    ## do calculations on dt
    dt[, colname:= 42]
}
```

If I call the function `renamer(colname = 'foo', dt=dt)`, the resulting column name will still be `colname`, not the value I passed, 'foo'.

The new column should be the string 'foo'

How could I do this? I've also tried with R data.frame, or trying something with

```
setnames(dt, "oldname", "newname")
```

EDIT: I think this question should be clarified:

Here is a data.table:

```
> library(data.table)
> DT = data.table(ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"), a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c = 13:18)
> DT
   ID a  b  c
1:  b 1  7 13
2:  b 2  8 14
3:  b 3  9 15
4:  a 4 10 16
5:  a 5 11 17
6:  c 6 12 18
```

I would like to create a function such that the new name of the column will be the string the user passes it.

e.g.

```
colnamer = function(newcolumname, datatable){
    ## do calculations on dt
    ## create a column with whatever string is passed via 'newcolumnname'
}
```

If the user calls `colnamer('foobar', DT)`, I would like the result to be

```
> DT
   ID a  b  c  foobar
1:  b 1  7 13   ...
2:  b 2  8 14   ...
3:  b 3  9 15   ...
4:  a 4 10 16   ...
5:  a 5 11 17   ...
6:  c 6 12 18   ...
```

Comment: Not too sure what you want? Do you want the column name for `colname` in `renamer` function to change or do you want to change the contents of `colname`? In the latter case I think this would work; `dt[, get(colname) := 42]`

Comment: @tstev I want the new column to be named a string the user passes in the function. e.g. in the above, `renamer(colname = 'foo', dt=dt)`, the new column would `foo`

Comment: @tstev The error I have with `get(colname)` is `Error in get(colname) : object 'foo' not found`

Comment: like `dt[[colname]] <- 42` ?

Comment: I am not a `data.table` expert but I think the line in `renamer` should be `dt[, (colname) := 42]`.

Comment: Ignore my first one. `set(dt, j = colname, value = 42)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Changed to OP's new reproducible example with two suggestions that worked as per OP's problem statement;

```
library(data.table) 
DT <- data.table(ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"), 
                 a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c = 13:18)

colnamer1 <- function(newcolumname, datatable) {
  ## do calculations on dt
  ## create a column with whatever string is passed via 'newcolumnname'
  set(datatable, j = newcolumname, value = 42)
}

colnamer2 <- function(newcolumname, datatable) {
  ## do calculations on dt
  ## create a column with whatever string is passed via 'newcolumnname'
  dt[, (newcolumname) := 42]
}

colnamer1("name_me", DT)
colnamer2("name_me_too", DT)
DT
#    ID a  b  c name_me name_me_too
# 1:  b 1  7 13      42          42
# 2:  b 2  8 14      42          42
# 3:  b 3  9 15      42          42
# 4:  a 4 10 16      42          42
# 5:  a 5 11 17      42          42
# 6:  c 6 12 18      42          42
```

A possible `data.frame` solution? Although ever since adopting `data.table` my `data.frame`-ing is a bit rusty. Perhaps there is a more elegant solution for your problem when it comes to a `data.frame`.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"), 
                 a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c = 13:18)
df_colnamer <- function(name_me, df) {
  new_df <- df
  new_df[[name_me]] <- 42
  new_df
}
new_df <- df_colnamer("foo", df)
new_df
#   ID a  b  c foo
# 1  b 1  7 13  42
# 2  b 2  8 14  42
# 3  b 3  9 15  42
# 4  a 4 10 16  42
# 5  a 5 11 17  42
# 6  c 6 12 18  42
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I wonder---how would one do this if it was a data.frame? Besides converting it to data.table...

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, then @Moody_Mudskipper's suggestion would work. But the advantage of `data.table` is that it can do it by reference in memory without having to create a copy.

Comment: There's a typo in `colnamer2`. It should be `datatable[, (newcolumname) := 42]`